# How to get a gooey effect with a lottie file?

Tags: javascript, css, lottie

I have created an animation in Aftereffects and using a filter I have added a gooey effect (link to the video below). Video files are very large so they can be negative for a website's performance. Therefore I like to use Lottie animations as a lightweight compromise where possible. From AE you can easily convert a composition into a JSON file which can be used as a Lottie animation. However, the gooey effect does not export into the Lottie file. How do I use a filter or some code to make the Lottie animation appear like the mp4 below?

Mp4 video the desired outcome: https://mango-media.eu/video/hero-01.mp4

I have tried adding a css filter to the parent container, but this does not work.

```
<div style="filter: blur(10px) contrast(15);">
    <div id="lottie-blob-1">
    </div>
</div>

<script>
  var blob = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
    container: document.getElementById('lottie-blob-1'),
    renderer: 'svg',
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    path: 'https://mango-media.eu/lottie/Hero-lottie-01.json'
  })
</script>
```

Comment: To achieve a similar effect but without Lottie (with which I have no experience, sorry) you could use HTML canvas to draw and animate circles, and then apply a blur filter and a contrast filter with CSS to get the goo effect. See an example codepen here: https://codepen.io/xubiod/pen/GQpGaK

Comment: thank you, this is a good solution. do you know if this sort of animation in multiple places on a page will effect performance negatively?

Comment: Both Canvas and Filter use GPU, so animating, blurring and contrasting several dozen circles across a few Canvases shouldn't have much of a performance effect on modern hardware if programmed correctly. Make sure to use requestAnimationFrame.